# How to get the correct information out of a dynamic layer with esri leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, esri, arcgis-js-api

Ok the problem is, that when i click on the map while having a dynamic layer on top of it the wrong information or no information is getting trough.

The example to make it more understandable:

The dynamic layer that will be added is:

```
    vestigingLayer1 = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer("http://ags101.prvgld.nl/arcgis/rest/services/IBIS_bedrijventerrein_app/IBIS_bedrijventerrein_app/MapServer",
        {
            layers: [0],
            position: 'front',
        })
map.addLayer(vestigingLayer1);
```

The codepart that reacts on the mouseclick on the layer is:

```
map.on("click", function(e) {

    if(typeof vestigingLayer1 === 'undefined'){
    }
    else{
        vestigingLayer1.identify(e.latlng, function(data) {
            if(data.results.length > 0) {
                // Popup toevoegen en informatie toevoegen
                 popupText =  "<div style='overflow:scroll; max-width:250px; max-height:260px;'>";
                 for (prop in data.results[0].attributes) {
                    var val = data.results[0].attributes[prop];
                    if (val != 'undefined' && val != "0" && prop !="OBJECTID" && prop != "Name") {
                        popupText += "<b>" + prop.replace(" (Esri)",'') + "</b>: " + val + "<br>";
                    }
                }
            popupText += "</div>";
            //Popup toevoegen op de plaats waar geklikt is.
            var popup = L.popup()
            .setLatLng(e.latlng)
            .setContent(popupText)
            .openOn(map);
            }
        });
    }
```

so if you follow the code part via firebug you can see that in data the results always give the information of the same layer(1) or it has no results.

Also a link to the working website to make it a bit more clear.
http://geodev.prvgld.nl/geoapp/definitief/kaart.html

If someone knows the answer to this i'm really grateful for it.

Comment: I tried to single out the layer where the information should come from with an IF statement, and somehow it says it doesn't have information.
Which is strange since in the database i can see there is more then enough information. Could this be, because the clickable part on the layer is a small dot/icon. Might there be somewhere in the webservice marked as dont give information? is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

By specifying this
 `layers: [0],`
in defining your dynamicMapLayer, you are only looking at a single layer in the service.

This could be why "the results always give the information of the same layer"